# Found element. but shown in Sleenium as not located

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Could someone please, help me to solve following confusion:
Want to pickup elements chosen in previous step which are looking as on screenshot below

[image]

used this in webdriver:

```
List<WebElement> sport = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='row tip-receipt']/div[@class='column large-6 tip-receipt-event']/dl/dd[1]"));
```

which when using online tool for checking xpath (this one: http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi) got result as on screenshot below:

[image]

And, when use it in selenium test, got this result:

```
 NoSuchElement no such element: Unable to locate element
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance

HTML is:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="column large-12 feedback">
<p class="feedback-item _07 warning">Feedback.section_not_completed</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="column large-12 text-center">
<div id="post-tip-loader-7" class="loader-large"><div>Loading..</div>    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="tip-post-analysis" class="tabbed-section" data-tab-title="3. Analysis">
<a style="position:absolute;top:10px;right:10px;z-index:2;" href="https://podio.com/webforms/6260741/487762" target="_blank">Report a bug</a>
<div class="row"><div class="column large-12"><h3 class="tabbed-section-  title">Analysis</h3></div></div>
<div class="row">
<div class="column large-12">
<input type="hidden" id="tip-oneliner" name="tip-oneliner" value="TIP ONELINER" data-counter="true">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="column large-12">
<label for="tip-analysis">Analysis</label>
<textarea class="has-wordcounter" id="tip-analysis" name="tip-analysis" data-counter="true" data-min-words="100" rows="15"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="column large-12 feedback">
<p class="feedback-item _08 warning">The preview does not meet the 100 words-requirement.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="column large-12">
<p>Tips must be exclusive. Rewrite your analysis if you've already made it available elsewhere online.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row tip-receipt">
<div class="column large-6 tip-receipt-event">
<dl>
<dt>Event</dt>
<dd></dd>
<dd>, </dd>
<dd></dd>
<dd></dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div class="column large-6 tip-receipt-prediction">
<dl>
<dt>Prediction</dt>
<dd>Bet type: </dd>
<dd>Stake: </dd>
<dd>Odds: </dd>
<dd>Bookmaker: </dd>
</dl>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="column large-12 feedback">
<p class="feedback-item _09 warning">You must complete this section before proceeding onto the next step.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="column large-12 text-center">
<div id="post-tip-loader-8" class="loader-large"><div>Loading..</div>    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="tip-post-upload" class="tabbed-section" data-tab-title="4. Publish">
<a style="position:absolute;top:10px;right:10px;z-index:2;" href="https://podio.com/webforms/6260741/487762" target="_blank">Report a bug</a>
<div class="row"><div class="column large-12"><h3 class="tabbed-section-title">Publish</h3></div></div>
<div class="row tip-receipt">
<div class="column large-6 tip-receipt-event" id="tplTipReceiptEvent">
<dl>
<dt>Event</dt>
<dd>{{sport}}</dd>
<dd>{{parentevent}}, {{country}}</dd>
<dd>{{event}}</dd>
<dd>{{eventtime}}</dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div class="column large-6 tip-receipt-prediction"  id="tplTipReceiptPrediction">
<dl>
<dt>Prediction</dt>
<dd>Bet type: {{bettype}}</dd>
<dd>Stake: {{stake}}</dd>
<dd>Odds: {{odds}}</dd>
<dd>Bookmaker: {{bookmaker}}</dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

Comment: Is driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='row tip-receipt']/div[@class='column large-6 tip-receipt-event'])) returning something ?
Otherwise using id attribute is quite confortable when it comes to testing front end.

Comment: @ teikitel it returns data as shown on screenshot 2

Comment: Either you have not shown us enough HTML or you misread my question but it is not possible it returns that.

Comment: @ teikitel added HTML

Comment: Can you try this path just to make selenium is matching the correct element "//div[@class='row tip-receipt']/div[@class='column large-6 tip-receipt-event'][1]/dl/dd[1]"

Comment: Found this:   **{{sport}}**

Comment: It means "//div[@class='row tip-receipt']/div[@class='column large-6 tip-receipt-event']" is matching several elements I think selenium is only searching into the first match "/dl/dd[1]" which is empty. Using a unique id in your div and searching it by id will be more robust and simpler.

Comment: Thank you @teikitel. I forgot about that, entirely

Comment: You helped me @ teikitel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not mentioned the HTML and there is no info if any frame is present, still I am attempting an answer.

If there is any frame then you need to switch on that frame first then only you can get the value

Another if you d1 tag is repeating you can try XPATH like below:

```
(//div[@class='row tip-receipt']/div[@class='column large-6 tip-receipt-event']/dl)[1]
```

Comment: regarding HTML, I added screenshot - first one.

Comment: It does not work since that there are two d1 and four dd (tried this option)

Comment: Add your sample HTML in question

Comment: Added HTML above

Comment: Hi there. Please try to refrain from adding "hope this helps" and other similar fluff. You have 430 answers with this phrase in, and it does not actually add anything to the meaning or substance of the answer. Volunteer editors will generally trim this sort of thing, so if you can save them work, it is often much appreciated.

Comment: sure will take care from now